# Rails 3: Where to write a non model specific method to be called in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know it might sound like a stupid question, but for my `index` method in my `record` controller i dont want to return all objects of `record`, some logic is applied to determine which `records` are displayed depending on the user logged in.

Where would i keep such a method that would take the user as a paramater and return an array of the records to be displayed in the index method and how would it be called? in the controller?

so it would be something like

```
def index
  @records = # get_records method would be called here
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why you couldn't (or shouldn't) put that logic in the index method of the controller, such as:

```
def index
  user_id = params['user']
  @records = Record.find_by_user(user_id)
end
```

Comment: I have the method ``find_by_user(current_user)`` in the ``record`` model and i tried calling the method like u said using ``Record.find_by_user(current_user)`` but it gives a ``undefined method `find_by_user`` did i do something wrong?

Comment: You've probably defined an instance method, but if you're calling it as `Record.find_by_user` it should be a class method.  But check first and make sure you need that method at all:  Active Record makes all kinds of dynamic look up methods for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the logic is more complex, I suggest, you put it into a (named) scope within the model. So for Rails 3, you would do:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :some_name, lambda {|user|
    # apply your logic here
  }

  ...
end
```